# ECDSA private and public keys - how to get SecretKey?

Tags: encryption, aes, bouncycastle, elliptic-curve, ecdsa

I have used `generateKeyPair()` method to generate 2 different `KeyPair` using ECDSA algorithm.

```
public KeyPair generateKeyPair(){           

    ECNamedCurveParameterSpec spec = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("secp192r1");
    KeyPairGenerator g = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDSA", "BC");
    g.initialize(spec, new SecureRandom());

    return g.generateKeyPair(); 
}
```

Then I used `PrivateKey` and `PublicKey` from separate `KeyPair` to get combined `SecretKey`:

```
private SecretKey generateSecretKey(PrivateKey privateKey, PublicKey publicKey) {

    KeyAgreement ka = KeyAgreement.getInstance("ECDH");
    ka.init(privateKey);
    ka.doPhase(publicKey),
            true);

    return ka.generateSecret("AES");
}
```

But I get at `ka.generateSecret("AES")`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.util.BaseAgreementSpi.engineGenerateSecret(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.KeyAgreement.generateSecret(KeyAgreement.java:648)
```

If I use ECDSA, I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm ECDSA not available
   at javax.crypto.KeyAgreement.getInstance(KeyAgreement.java:184)
```

Using DH throws:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.InvalidKeyException: DHKeyAgreement requires DHPrivateKey
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.dh.KeyAgreementSpi.engineInit(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.KeyAgreement.implInit(KeyAgreement.java:346)
    at javax.crypto.KeyAgreement.chooseProvider(KeyAgreement.java:378)
    at javax.crypto.KeyAgreement.init(KeyAgreement.java:470)
```

How to get combined `SecretKey` from `PrivateKey` and `PublicKey` which are generated using ECDSA algorithm?

Comment: Which version of BouncyCastle do you use? Also make sure not to use OpenJDK as it misses ECDSA support in some Linux distributions.

Comment: bcpkix-jdk15on 1.54. It works well for sign and verify in Windows and Linux.

Comment: I don’t know BouncyCastle, but looking at your code I notice a couple of things that might cause the problem. First it looks like you are generating ECDSA keys, but trying to use them in DH key agreement—perhaps the key is the wrong format? Second, do you need to provide the curve details to `KeyAgreement` object? I see it provides [an overloaded `init` method that accepts an `AlgorithmParameterSpec`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/KeyAgreement.html#init-java.security.Key-java.security.spec.AlgorithmParameterSpec-).

Comment: If I use ECDSA for KeyAgreement, I get exception "Algorithm ECDSA not available". When curve spec is provided, it throws "Parameters not supported". However, it works well if I generateSecret("DES") instead of AES.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works correctly and returns curve size shared secret after removing "AES" argument from `return ka.generateSecret();`:

```
private SecretKey generateSecretKey(PrivateKey privateKey, PublicKey publicKey) {

    KeyAgreement ka = KeyAgreement.getInstance("ECDH");
    ka.init(privateKey);
    ka.doPhase(publicKey, true);

    return ka.generateSecret();
}
```

Comment: It's working for me. How do i convert the secretkey into String?

Comment: Convert bytes to Hex or Base64 string.

Answer (score 0):

A key agreement protocol usually works between two parties each of them having an own ECDS public and private key (hence we have four different keys). Are you sure that is what you want?

Therefore when you agree to a key you need the **private key of party A** and the **public key of party B**. And on the other end of the connection you use the private key of party B and the public key of party A.

The ECDH key agreement algorithm you selected is described in [RFC3278](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3278.txt) - for details read it.

Comment: I know, I use private key and public keys from separate key pairs. The problem is that I get the exception when generating SecretKey.